# HP-Envy 4500 All-in-one printer appears to lose wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, printing, hp

I am on 14.04 and successfully installed the HP-Envy 4500 All-in-one printer.

It worked a treat printing via wireless / scanning etc.

I don't print that often (probably a few pages every 3 weeks) , but when I print now, Ubuntu goes through the print routines , says it's started and finished OK, but HPLIP shows a status of 'Held' because it thinks the printer is not connected to the wifi.

If I reboot my wireless router and reboot the printer it will 'sometimes' work, but more than often it gives me the same error.

If I try to browse to the printers IP address (to get the printer configuration menu), Firefox cannot connect.

If I plug a USB connection from my laptop to the printer, hey presto, the printer works fine.

I am finding this frustrating. I can print to the printer via my HTC smart phone without any issues , but Ubuntu seems very problematic when attempting to print over wifi

I noticed this problem after I had had a power outage, although the issue may have been there before the outage. All my equipment is connected through a circuit breaker

Is there a fix for this? Any tips or advice would be most welcome. I am not a Linux / Ubuntu expert by any means but I can follow step by step guides etc.

Thank you in anticipation of your help

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it helps, but I have the same printer with no problem at all. It's connected to a B/G wifi router, using WPA2 encription.

The only important thing I had to do is preallocate the IP number of the printer in the router static DHCP configuration, so that it would not change across reconnections.

This thing is different from router to router, so you have to find it on your device  --- this is the screenshot for my router:

[image]

Comment: thanks I will try it tomorrow. The IP address of my printer is meant to be 192.168.0.16 but I cannot access it via firefox. Is it likely to have been allocated another address and if so how do I find what it is ?

Comment: You shuold be able to find somewhere in your router menus a "list of connected devices" or "DHCP leases" or similar thing.Or in the printer panel, if you access the wireless menu you have the IP in the top line.

Comment: cheers Rmano, I am at work at the moment , so will try tonight. The one thing that puzzles me though is my HTC Desire mobile can print to the printer via wireless , but Ubuntu has the intermittent fault. If I try to print the same document at the same time, the phone works and Ubuntu fails :(

Comment: But they probably use different protocols --- the HP "over the air" print protocol will search for the printer and find it even if it changes IP; I suspect that CUPS is not able to do that. Then it could be another thing, but I have had no problem at all with the fixed IP.

Comment: Rmano, I looked at my Router (a virginmedia superhub2) and the ip address for connected devices is a display only screen i.e. you cannot adjust the IP address manually. The IP address for the printer was showing the correct address ! Maybe I need to try a firmware update on the printer or maybe just shut down my printer and router for 10 mins and do a reboot of the router followed by a reboot of the printer. That has worked OK for me once , but not a second time. It is very frustrating !

Comment: It seems that you *can* do reservations: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dr46nhKhHI4 (although there seems to be bugs around... YMMV http://community.virginmedia.com/t5/Wireless-Networking/Superhub-2-DHCP-Reservation-not-saving-settings/td-p/2201422/page/3 )

Comment: Rmano thanks for the link to youtube and the advice on "reservations". The reservation has fixed the issue. The video suggested disconnecting the printer and rebooting the router before adding the reservation, but all I did was disconnect the printer and add the reservation and then reboot my laptop. Excellent advice my friend. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same printer.  Works great.  First I found the printer was going to sleep and when I went to print to it it was asleep and would not wake up by the signal from from the computer.

There are two ways you can fix this.  In the printer menu, find the place and tell the printer to not go to sleep (not really the best because it is on constantly). The simplest solution is to turn the printer off when you are not using it.  But turn it on when you boot your computer and it will be ready to print for you.